# Replace string in another file with sed from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace the value of an environment variable definition, if it exists, from a bash script. I know I can use `sed` to do this, I'm not sure, however, how to replace the value of the environment variable?

Here's what I'd like to do:

Given a file with this line (found with `grep`):

```
export MY_ENV=SOME_VALUE
```

I'd like to replace `SOME_VALUE` with something else. How do I do that with `sed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This searches for the line beginning with `export MY_ENV=` and substitutes the rest of the line with `NEW_VALUE`:

```
sed 's/^\(export MY_ENV=\).*$/\1NEW_VALUE/'
```

Comment: Also, `sed -i` will modify the file in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/SOME_VALUE/$MY_ENV/"
```

This locates the string `SOME_VALUE` and substitutes the value of `$MY_ENV`.  The double quotes are crucial; don't use single quotes unless you want `$`, `M`, `Y`, ... in the replacement text.